# Debian update without data loss

Tags: debian, apt, software-updates

Is it possible to update the Debian distribution without losing the old settings, configuration, files and folders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not very specific in your question as to what you have already read or tried.

[This little manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/uptodate.en.html) will inform in depth on how to keep your system up to date.

Short Answer: You do *not* have to use an ISO file, in most cases Debian can be upgraded using `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I'd use the command 'apt' as opposed to 'apt-get'(It's the new thing apparently). 'apt update',upgrade and full upgrade should suffice. Also one is usually prompted to overwrite yes|no when configuration files are updated. Installing apt-listchanges should help in this regard too.